Equilibration/Thermalization in mean-field theory
Assume a scalar field in $D$ spacetime dimensions with a quartic interaction
$$H=\int d^{D-1}x\;\left(\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi+\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2+\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4\right)$$
This system can be analyzed within the mean field theory, where
we introduce a condensate $\sigma=\langle\phi^2\rangle$. Then, we have
$$H_{\rm MF}=\int d^{D-1}x\;\left(\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi+\frac{1}{2}\left(m^2+\frac{2\lambda}{4!}\sigma\right)\phi^2\right),$$
where the mass term is shifted and I neglect a constant term in the Hamiltonian. The new mass now depends on the state via the condensate $\sigma=\langle\phi^2\rangle$. My question is the following: in this kind of descriptions, how does the thermalization process take place? I mean, usually if one takes the state out-of-equilibrium (e.g. performing a quench in the bare mass $m$), the state is no longer an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian and therefore evolves until a time when it reaches an equilibrium. This, however, happens within the exact description of free theories. For interacting theories treated via mean-field, the time-evolution becomes non-linear and therefore I am not sure about what to expect with respect to relaxation/equilibration/thermalization.

See the so called relaxational dynamics: model A, model B, and so on. The typical source is https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.49.435
